# Equations in org-reveal presentation

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-babel, org-reveal

I've installed `reveal.js` and `org-reveal`, and they are working as expected. Even, I'm getting the equations!

However, the point with the equations is the following: If I introduce directly the LaTeX code

```
\begin{equation*}
  E  = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{a \neq b} \frac{e_a e_b}{r_{ab}}
\end{equation*}
```

equations are shown in the exported reveal presentation, but if I use the LaTeX export

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
\begin{equation*}
  E  = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{a \neq b} \frac{e_a e_b}{r_{ab}}
\end{equation*}
#+END_EXPORT
```

the equations are not shown!!!

Why do I want to use the export block?

Because I can treat the block as native LaTeX, and use `yasnippets` or LaTeX shortcuts...

*Question:* What should I do to change this behaviour?

---

*Alternative question:* What should I do to load the LaTeX yasnipets together with those of org?

Comment: A LaTeX export block is only exported when you are exporting to LaTeX/PDF. In all other cases (e.g exporting to HTML), it is *skipped*. I don't think you can change that behaviour without redesigning the export engine. I cannot help with the alternative question.

Comment: Thank you @Nick I was suspecting that would be the issue.